# Is Knowhere the remains of Ego's skull?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

Is Knowhere, the severed skull of an unknown Celestial floating in space, actually in fact the physical remains that once housed the brain of the Celestial Ego?

Comment: One might argue that the original question may have/need an updated answer, but this is a dupe question.

Comment: Is it, since the original question and answer may be different with the release of GOTG2?

Comment: And do you see a way to edit it to incorporate the new release and new information with make it unique?

Comment: Yes, it's a dupe. They both ask which Celestial's skull it is. If you believe the other question needs a fresher, more updated answer due to possible new information, you are welcome to offer a bounty (or get someone else to do it).

Comment: Given they mentioned mining brain tissue in the first movie, and Ego still had his brain at that point, I would think not.

Comment: @Jack Agreed, especially given that "Knowhere" seems to be a very well-established mining colony.